# Sum quantity from 2 different tables where they have an id that which from other table

Tags: sql

ProdStock
ID_Prod       Description
1                          tshirt
2                          pants
3                          hat

Donation
id_dona        ID_Prod         Quantity
1                              1                           10
2                              2                          20
3                              1                           30
4                              3                           5

Beneficiation
id_bene         ID_Prod          Quantity
1                                1                           -5
2                                2                          -10
3                                1                          -15

Table expected
ID_Prod         Description          Quantity
1                                tshirt                           20
2                                pants                          10
3                                hat                              5

Donation = what is given to the institution
beneficiation= institution gives to people in need
i need to achieve "Table expected" , i tried with sum. I dont have much knowledge in sql, it would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Please refer to http://www.sscce.org. This question would benefit from having the expected outcome listed, along with what sql code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have no idea what database you're actually working with, here is an idea how you might get in the right direction:

```
Select ProdStock.ID_Prod, ProdStock.Description,
       (Sum(Donation.Quantity) + Sum(Beneficiation.Quantity)) as Quantity
  From ProdStock
         Inner Join Donation on ProdStock.ID_Prod=Donation.ID_Prod
         Inner Join Beneficiation on ProdStock.ID_Prod=Beneficiation.ID_Prod
  Group By ProdStock.ID_Prod, ProdStock.Description;
```

Comment: Do you actually need to create a separate table or view? Otherwise, the proposed query already returns the data in the expected structure.